# How can you create accessible headings with levels in extjs 6?

Tags: extjs, accessibility, wai-aria

In extjs 6, is there a way to specify that a component is a heading of a particular level for purposes of accessibility? I can force a component to add a role="heading" attribute using the ariaRole configuration, i.e.

```
{
  xtype: 'component',
  ariaRole: 'heading'
}
```

Is it possible to force it to set an aria-level attribute? I've tried using the ariaAttributes configuration with no success. Or, is there some other way to create an accessible, screen reader compliant hierarchy of heading elements?

Comment: Can you not do  `{html: '<h2>content<h2>'}` and just set it that way?

Comment: That should work. I was hoping there was a more general "sencha like" way that didn't involve hand rolling the html, but sometimes I guess you have to get down to bare metal.

Comment: When it comes to accessibility, semantically correct elements are 50 times better than using `aria`. I have a feeling you might need to do a few "bare metal" tweaks like this but in the long run it will be way easier to maintain than a "sea of `aria` attributes" to manage! Good luck in the project!